# How can I apply a linear gradient to fill in chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I use chart.js and vue-chartjs

I need make fill (start) with gradient:

```
linear-gradient(180deg, #7F56D9 0%, rgba(127, 86, 217, 0) 95.55%);
```

like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y77Wr.png)

My config

```
const chartData = {
labels: ['2022-01','2022-02','2022-03','2022-04','2022-05','2022-06','2022-07', '2022-08','2022-09', '2022-10', '2022-11', '2022-12'],
datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [420,430,680,560,790,240,395,830,810, 430, 500, 700],
        borderColor: '#7F56D9',
        borderWidth: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#7F56D9',
        fill: 'start'
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
backgroundColor: (context) => {
            const ctx = context.chart.ctx;
            const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(127,86,217,0.1)");
            gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(127, 86, 217, 0)");
            return gradient;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradients on canvas are created using [canvas.createLinearGradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient)

You'd need to do something like this for `backgroundColor`:

```js
datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: [420, 430, 680, 560, 790, 240, 395, 830, 810, 430, 500, 700],
      borderColor: '#7F56D9',
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: 'start',
      backgroundColor: (ctx) => {
        const canvas = ctx.chart.ctx;
        const gradient = canvas.createLinearGradient(0, -160, 0, 120);

        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#7F56D9');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, '#fff');

        return gradient;
      },
    },
  ],
```

[image]

It's about as close as I could get to your image.

CSS `linear-gradient` and canvas `createLinearGradient` aren't related and have no 1:1 translation (as far as I know), so you'll just need to play around with the numbers until you get a gradient close to what you want.

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-gradient plugin

Comment: Thanks. I did it like this backgroundColor: (context) => {
                const ctx = context.chart.ctx;
                const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
                gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(127,86,217,0.1)");
                gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(127, 86, 217, 0)");
                return gradient;
            }